# fill dropdown with selectik jquery pulgin

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using Jquery plugin selectik. I am trying to fill the dropdownlist from database based on my first dropdown selection. I am using MVC 5. I am using the following code on the change event of my firstdropdown. I am not able to view the values in the dropdown. But when I press F12 and look for the dropdown I can see the values are there. Can any help how to use seleckik plugin.

```
 ***function company_change() {
        $("#automodel").empty();
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetAutoModel")', { CompanyModel: $("#company").val() }, function (cdata) {
            $.each(cdata, function () {
                $("#automodel").append("<option value='" + this.AutoModelId + "'>" + this.AutoModelName + "</option>");
            });
        });
        $("#automodel").data("selectik").regreshCS();
    }***
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let me explain how the plugin works, there is no way to apply style on dropdowns.
so this plugin will hide the actual drop down and instead create drop down like structure using other html elements(div, span...) with the values which are stored in data-selectik attribute if available otherwise it will use option name.
You need refreshCS() because when you update options in the actual drop-down the plugin does not know about the update, when you call refreshCS() it re-reads the data and re-render the visible drop-down.

- add an attribute to all the options of the select element you are applying the plugin, The plugin is internally using that attribute to show the names, it is an option value if you want to format the name which you can not do in actual options, like this

  `<option value="1" data-selectik="Spider man">Spider man<option>`
- The function to refresh the select after the new data updated is **refreshCS** not regreshCS
  ie `$("#automodel").data("selectik").refreshCS();`

Put the refreshCS inside the success method, getJson is Async call so, the last line was being executed regardless of result of getJSON call.

```
function company_change() {
        $("#automodel").empty();
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetAutoModel")', { CompanyModel: $("#company").val() }, function (cdata) {
            $.each(cdata, function () {
                $("#automodel").append("<option data-selectik='" + this.AutoModelName + "' value='" + this.AutoModelId + "'>" + this.AutoModelName + "</option>");
            });
            $("#automodel").data("selectik").refreshCS();
        });

    }
```

Comment: still the output is same. The new added items are not visible. But can you explain me what is this regreshCS? and data("selectik"). I try to search on this but not able to find out any detail.

Comment: in your code $("#automodel").data("selectik").regreshCS(); was outside
function (cdata) {}, when the getJSON call returns it will call function (cdata) {}

Comment: Bundle of thanks Amit, I was spelling wrong refreshCS. as I correct it, I am able to see the data. But one question, .empty() is not working. If value is changed in 1 dropdown the new values I get in second dropdown but the selected value is still showing the old value.

Comment: I got it, by using the following statement we can select the selected index value  $("#ddlAutoModel").data("selectik").changeCS({ index: 1 });